# Save picture from camera to SQLlite as blob

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I'm trying to solve some issue. I need to take picture from camera and save it to database (sqllite), after that i want to upload it all at the end of the day. I spent several hours to solve it.

My question is how to save picture to local database for my task. I tried to convert result form camera (blob:http://localhost:44000/...) to base64 but it takes long time.

Maybe there is more effectively way to make it?